# Can Webbots delete content from my website using links that are wired to GET requests?

Tags: php, http-get, delete-file

OK here my problem: **content is disappearing from my site**. It's not the most secure site out there, it has a number of issues. Right now every time I upload a page that can delete content from the my site using simple links wired to a GET request I find the corresponding content being deleted in mass.

Example, I have a functionality on my site to upload images. Once the user uploads an image, the admin(the owner) can use another page to delete all(owned) images from the site. The delete functionality is implemented in such a way that a user clicks on the link under each thumbnail of uploaded images he would send a get request that deletes the image information from the site's database and deletes the image from the server file system.

The other day I uploaded that functionality and the next morning I found all my images deleted. The pages are protected using user authentication when you view the pages using a browser. To my surprise, however, I could **wget** that page with out any problem.

So I was wondering if **some evil web bot was deleting my content using those links?** Is that possible? What do you advice for further securing my website.

Comment: Using GET to do modifications on a website is generally a bad idea. Some Browsers are prefetching all GET requests on a given page to speed up browsing, therefore executing those links. Switch to POST (or even better HTTP DELETE)

Comment: Apart from that, I'd say that your user authentication is not working.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I think your right. I just found a serious bug. Can't wait to move to a proper web framework.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible. Even non-evil web bots could be doing it. The Google bot doesn't know the link it follows has any specific functionality.

The easiest way to possibly address this is to setup a proper robots.txt file to tell the bots not to go to specific pages. Start here: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: Thanks @Eric just add that to my server. I've read I need to make sure that other non-compliant bots that ignore this file do not access my files. I think .htaccess is the way to go for this. Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 2616 (HTTP protocol), section 9.1.1: Safe Methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> The convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe". This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

Basically, if your application allows deletion via GET requests, it's doing it wrong. Bots will follow public links, and they have no obligation to expect to delete things when doing so, and neither do browsers. If the links are protected it could still be browser prefetching or acceleration of some kind.

Edit: [It might also be Bing. Nowadays Internet Explorer sends data to Microsoft about everywhere you go to gather data for its shitty search engine.](http://searchengineland.com/google-bing-is-cheating-copying-our-search-results-62914)

Comment: thanks for the input. We just used the GET method just to get things working fast. What a very bad idea that was! We'll be making the changes pronto. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a search-bot will scan a page for any links and peek down those links to see what pages are behind that. So yeah, if a both has access to that page, the page contains links to delete items / stuff and the both opens those links to see what's behind them, the code simply gets triggered.

There's a couple of ways to block bots from scanning pages. Look into robot.txt implementations. Also, you might want to look into the mechanism / safety of your admin authentication system... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the robots.txt file to block the access for some web bots.
And for those that don't look for the robots.txt file you can also use javascript, there shouldn't be many webbots interpreting it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.location.href='./delete'; return false;">delete</a>
```